# Создать страницу с фоном любого цвета, при клике в любую область которой осуществляется закрашивание фигуры определенного размера

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

В общем-то дело такое: необходимо создать страницу с фоном любого цвета, при клике в любую область которой осуществляется закрашивание фигуры определенного размера.

*Вот собственно сам код:*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Page</title>
            <script type = "text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <form>
                <div id="myCanvas" width="300"; height="300"; background-color: blue></div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                $('body').click(function(){
                    let c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                    let ctx = c.getContext("2d");
                    ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 150, 100);
                });
                </script>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

*Скриншот:*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы хотите закрасить выделенный квадрат?

Comment: непонятно, что именно вам нужно. есть кнопка `править`, нажмите на нее и дополните вопрос

Comment: сейчас выложу скриншот того, что мне необходимо сделать.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canv');
canvas.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if (canvas.getContext) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillRect(e.clientX - 30, e.clientY - 85 , 50, 50);
  }
});
```

```css
#canv {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canv">
</canvas>
```

[Определение координат](http://shpargalkablog.ru/2013/05/get-mouse-coordinates-inside-div.html)

[Рисование на Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes)

Comment: @IvanLabozhevich если вам помог мой ответ, буду благодарен за то что вы его выберете как правиьный (галочку слева поставите)